# Ubuntu stuck on black screen in boot

Tags: installation, boot

The computer I'm trying to install on has NO other os on it.
After seeing the screen that asks if I want to

```
Try ubuntu without installing
Install ubuntu
Check disk for defects
Test memory
Boot from first hard disk
```

I select install Ubuntu and it takes me to the normal black screen BUT mine gets stuck on it and never continues the boot.

After this I tried using a USB that I created with netbooter or something, after clicking install Ubuntu it says binary white listed and doesn't work.

Comment: Depending on how long into the boot process you get you might be able to press the escape key and identify which step it hangs on.
Also try installing from a [minimal cd](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) and see if that goes any better.